# Jquery Libraries to draw route on SVG map

Tags: jquery, svg, maps

I have a web application that has live floor SVG map inserted into it.
I can do some events like highlighting/tap/click whenever the customer search for a specific place.

**For example:** if the customer search for parking area, i can highlight the parking area. But i prefer drawing a route like Google maps get directions. i go-ogled it and found very less. so i came here for expert answers.

Are there any good SVG/Jquery libraries available to achieve them?  any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may try Raphael JS. It's actually a nice Javascript library for drawing SVG and it is supported most browsers.